# Exportar tabla filtrada a CSV con PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera exportar a CSV los datos de una tabla, pero solo los datos que marco en un checkbox. Con el código que tengo me exporta los datos marcados, pero me los va repitiendo al igual que la cabecera. Me falta algo que haga que se exporte correctamente lo marcado en el checkbox, pero no puedo ver que es. Espero que me podáis ayudar.

```
    //get records from database
$idusuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$datos = $mysqli->query("select * from partidas");

if( !isset($_POST['casilla']) OR !is_array($_POST['casilla']) ) {
    exit('No se ha seleccionado ningun dato para la exportacion');
}
        
        $delimiter = ",";
        $filename = "Partidas_Abiertas" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
    
        //create a file pointer
        $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
       
       //creaa los encabezados de las columnas
        $fields = array('Cuenta', 'NombreCliente', 'KZz','zv', 'Doc.Factura', 'Fecha_Factura','Venc.Neto', 'Importe_en_ML', 'texto');
        fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);


        //extrae cada fila de datos, les da formato csv y los escribe en fichero creado
        
        foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $value) {
    
        $value="Select * from partidas where id_partida = $value LIMIT 1"; 
        $result = $mysqli->query($value);
        while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $lineData = array($d[cuenta], $d[nCliente], $d[kzz], $d[zv],  $d[docFac], $d[fechaDoc], $d[vencNeto], $d[importe], $d[texto]);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
    
    //vuelve al principio de cada fila
    fseek($f, 0);
    
     //crea las cabeceras para la exportacion para descarga del archivo con el nombre y fecha
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
   
    
    //Escribe toda la informacion restante de un puntero a un archivo 
    fpassthru($f);
}
exit;

?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no los filtras directamente en el `select` que pasas a `query()`?

Comment: Mónica, en tu pregunta no comentas qué es lo que quieres filtrar. Es cierto que lo mejor sería filtrar en la Base de Datos directamente.
Además, declaras un par de variables que no se sabe para qué las quieres utilizar... `$idusuario`, que no sé si será para filtrar registros de ese usuario, y `$status`, que me imagino que será también para exportarlo en el CSV en formato legible y que no incluyes ni en los nombres de columna ni en el array de daots `$lineData`

Comment: Gracias a los dos por vuestros comentarios. Me refiero a que si tengo una tabla de 100 resultados y los filtro por uno de los campos de la tabla y me quedan 5 que solo se exporten esos 5

Comment: Explica con claridad qué es lo que quieres filtrar, pues no termina de entenderse. Y dinos por qué no filtras ya los datos en la consulta SQL usando un `WHERE`. Lo lógico es que si quieres datos filtrados, los traigas ya en los resultados, no que traigas todo para luego filtrar de forma programática. Lo único que justificaría esa práctica sería que necesites los otros datos para otra cosa en ese mismo contexto.

Comment: Vale, me explico. El usuaio al ver la tabla necesita ver todos los datos que hay en ella y si quiere por ejemplo ver los de un determinado cliente, puede filtar por nombre de cliente o id de cliente en la tabla o algún otro dato, en el frontend desde el buscador, y los datos que traiga ese filtro (que serán 1 o 5 o 10) poder exportarlos, no la tabla entera. No traigo los datos filtrados, porque es el usuario el que desde el buscador filtraría los datos que quiere ver de toda la tabla.

Comment: Bien, pues dicho eso, no tiene ningún sentido lo que intentas hacer aquí. Si el usuario dispone ya de todos los datos en el cliente, y quiere filtrar parte de esos datos, lo que debes hacer es escribir código en el cliente (Javascript) para que los datos se filtren. Y si hace falta generar un `.csv` con los datos filtrados, no hay ningún problema, lo puedes generar desde el cliente, mediante Javascript. Por tanto, creo que tu problema es más bien de enfoque.

Comment: Monica, con tu comentario me queda un poco más clara la función de este script. Por ejemplo, vamos a llamarlo exportador_csv.php
Pero la clave está en el origen de llamada a este script. Por ejemplo... ¿es desde un formulario donde estableces los filtros? Si fuera así, por ejemplo, deberías obtener los campos de filtrado desde este fichero (por ejemplo `$_POST['cliente']` o `$_POST['tipoContrato']` o los que fueran).
¿Quiero decir... desde dónde se llama a este archivo? ¿Desde un formulario directo? ¿Desde una instrucción JS?...

Comment: Os he contestado editando mi pregunta. AHora consigo mediante un checkbox marccar las filas de la tabla que quiero exportar y lo hace, pero se repiten los datos. es decir que si marco dos filas me las duplica y exporta 4, al igual que la cabecera. por cada fila que marco, me exporta la fila y la cabecera y por duplicado. Me podéis ayudar en lo que me falta que no veo por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código no funciona por varios motivos:

1. Para ir agregando líneas, tienes que abrir el archivo en modo `a`, que significa *append* o *agregar* ([revisa el Manual de PHP para entender el significado de cada modo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php)).
2. Tienes los `header` y `fpassthru` **dentro de bucle** y eso es lo que hace que se genere contenido sobre-escrito en la memoria. Si sacas esas líneas del bucle se creará un solo archivo con el contenido que se haya ido agregando.
3. Tu forma de crear `$lineData` en el bucle no es correcta, no al menos en versiones modernas de PHP. La sintaxis para obtener valores de arrays asociativos es `$elArray["laLlave"]` o `$elArray['laLlave']`, o sea, usar comillas simples o dobles para las llaves. Otra cosa sería si estuvieras concatenando, pero no es el caso aquí. Si `$lineData` recoge todas las columnas del `SELECT`, puedes crearlo así simplemente: `$lineData=array_values($d);`

Así debería funcionar:

```
if( !isset($_POST['casilla']) OR !is_array($_POST['casilla']) ) {
    exit('No se ha seleccionado ningun dato para la exportacion');
}
        
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "Partidas_Abiertas" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
    
    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'a');
       
    //crea los encabezados de las columnas
    $fields = array('Cuenta', 'NombreCliente', 'KZz','zv', 'Doc.Factura', 'Fecha_Factura','Venc.Neto', 'Importe_en_ML', 'texto');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    //extrae cada fila de datos, les da formato csv y los escribe en fichero creado
        
    foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $value) {
    
        $value="Select * from partidas where id_partida = $value LIMIT 1"; 
        $result = $mysqli->query($value);
        while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $lineData = array($d["cuenta"], $d["nCliente"], $d["kzz"], $d["zv"],  $d["docFac"], $d["fechaDoc"], $d["vencNeto"], $d["importe"], $d["texto"]);
            fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
        }
    
        //vuelve al principio de cada fila
        fseek($f, 0);    
    }
     //crea las cabeceras para la exportacion para descarga del archivo con el nombre y fecha
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\";");
     
    //Escribe toda la informacion restante de un puntero a un archivo 
    fpassthru($f);
    exit;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones. AHora funciona correctamente.